# Ceiling light goes off itself

Tags: electrical, lighting

My ceiling light goes off itself after 10 mins or sometimes even after an hour, no loose connection from the ceiling fixture and the switch, nothing seems loose even breaker too. How can i find the problem and what is causing to shut off itself? 5 LED bulbs was working fine about 2 years and suddenly went wrong? need help, thanks

---

Actually I am helping with my friend's living room ceiling fixture; they did not put any extra load on same circuit and bulbs could be issue but I really want to know it could be switch problem too. The light goes off slowly with a couple of flickers before it goes off, and you can not turn back on right away, even if you try to turn it on. I can only turn it on 5-10 mins after going off. It could be a switch issue, maybe the switch is not passing the power to the fixture. The funny thing is that when I opened the fixture, I did not see any transformer on the fixture. I don't know where it gets overheated if there is no transformer.

Comment: If you have a multi-meter, take off the switch cover plate and check voltage. Check voltage on all receptacles as well. Wait for the light to go off and check all voltages again. This way you can trace the circuit and locate the voltage drop. If you have a voltage drop everywhere, it's probably a bad breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you recently added an appliance or other large load in the same circuit?

I had an interesting dilemma similar to this once. I kept changing a customer's bulbs as they were continuously blowing. It turns out that she had plugged a mini fridge into the bedroom outlet with an extension cord. The light was in the circuit after the fridge and was only getting about 40 volts when the fridge turned on, blowing the light. I moved the fridge and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Heat is an enemy for LED bulbs, and many bulbs say specifically that they cannot be used in an enclosed fixture since there is no airflow and a build up of heat.  I tested this with some LED bulbs from IKEA, and sure enough, in an enclosed fixture they would turn on and off as they heated up.

It could be that your bulbs used to be fine, but the heat has slowly degraded them.  Check the bulbs and see if they mentioned use in an enclosed fixture.  Either way, replacing the bulbs with the appropriate type is probably your best bet.

Comment: Sometimes even the enclosures have heat-sensitive switches not likely the culprit with LED's installed.